# customize next and previous pagination button in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-paginate

I'm unable to customize previous and next button with laravel 5.0 app.
All I'm getting is `>>` `<<`, but I want to make it more simpler: is there any way?

Comment: What i Can say its could be pagination not design well to deal such requirement however there is some package to helps `https://github.com/Landish/Pagination`

Answer (score 0):

**i found most simplest way**

all I wanted was to replace << with my choice of text like back, same with >> I did something that might be useful

```
@if($results->previousPageUrl())
    <a href="{{ route('your.route') . '/url/' . $results->previousPageUrl() }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Back</a>
@endif
@if($results->nextPageUrl())
    <a href="{{ route('your.route') . '/url/' . $results->nextPageUrl() }}" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-sm">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel 5.1 and I see that render() method in **BootstrapThreePresenter** is not calling $this->getPreviousButton() with argument populated from lang/en/pagination.php, as I guess it should be. And getPreviousButton() has default parameter `$text = '&laquo;'`

So, yes I think it's framework mallfunction. I am sending push request now so I hope it will be fixed in next release.